# Should I setup index on a table having 15k -30k row?

Tags: mysql, database, indexing

I have a table we will be of 15-30k in size eventually not more.

I have only two columns in that table one is `id` and other is `status`

- We will have insert queries ofc
- We will have update query but not on id
- We will have delete query

My question is should I create index on the column `id` ?

Will index be useful for a table having 15k-30k rows ? Or will it be negligible ?

Also I am concerned about the increase in cost of insert queries? Will it be worth to add index on `id` ? Considering the small table size will it be any faster or the effect will be negligible ?
If effect will be negligible, I should not add index to it right as it will increase the insert queries cost right ?

Comment: To make sure we are answering your questions, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and a sample Update and Delete.

Answer (score 1):

If your `id` column is a **PRIMARY KEY**, then it's already an index and there is no need to create a new one.
If no primary key is defined, it's best to get used of creating one for each table.

Without any index, MySQL has to start with the first row and go through the whole table to find the relevant rows.
Indexes make it possible to find data much faster, even on tables with few data.

*MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-indexes.html*